# Web Service url

Tags: java, jboss

I have an EAR project, which contains my application's version number in its name. Inside it I have a JAR for my session beans (the JAR also has a version number in its name). Inside that jar, I have a web service implementation.

So far so good. The problem is that the path to the WSDL is something like: host:port/application_name_and_version-jar_name_and_version/WS_name?WSDL. This means that every time a new version comes along, the WS client has to be adjusted.

This whole thing is deployed in JBoss.

The question is, how do I change the URL so it does not contain version numbers? I assume it has to do with deployment descriptors, but so far I was unable to find any useful information on this.

Comment: If the version number only denotes major changes, then this might be a feature not a bug, for it means that you can have multiple versions of the service, so that older clients don't all have to be changed when a new version is deployed as they can use the old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a .war file containing only the web service implementation, then give the war its own context root inside the .ear file's `application.xml`.  For example:

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">

  <module>
```

<java>shared-code.jar</java>

```
  <module>
    <ejb>my-ejbs.jar</ejb>
  </module>

  <module>
```

<web>
          <web-uri>my-web-service.war</web-uri>
          <context-root>webserviceroot</context-root>
        </web>
      </module>
 
      <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
    </application>

Sorry about the formatting, I can't get StackOverflow to make a contiguous code block from the above after messing with it a bit.

Anyway, if you deploy an .ear file like that, then you should be able to access `http://host:port/webserviceroot/...` instead.

Comment: And we've got the perfect answer. Did just that and works as expected. Thank you.